# MVC with Azure Entra ID Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, azure-app-registration

I have just created a new MVC project and created an App Registration in Azure. Below is my code that I currently have:

Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AzureAccount", policyBuilder => {
                policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new PolicyRequirement());
            });
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PolicyAuthorizationHandler>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        if ( env.IsDevelopment() ) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

PolicyAuthorizationHandler.cs

```cs
public class PolicyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PolicyRequirement>
{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public PolicyAuthorizationHandler(DataContext dataContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationHandlerContext, PolicyRequirement policyRequirement) {
        if ( await policyRequirement.Pass(_httpContextAccessor, _dataContext) ) {
            authorizationHandlerContext.Succeed(policyRequirement);
        }
    }
}
```

PolicyRequirement.cs

```cs
public class PolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public async Task<bool> Pass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, DataContext dataContext) {
        bool authorized = false;

        if ( dataContext is not null ) {
            string? email = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User.Identity?.Name;

            if ( email is not null ) {
                User? user = dataContext.Users.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Active).FirstOrDefault();

                if ( user is not null ) {

                    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new();
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new(ClaimTypes.Email, email));
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name));
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role));

                    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

                    authorized = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(authorized);
    }
}
```

My HomeController has the `[Authorize("AzureAccount")]` attribute and the Index method of this controller has the line `var identities = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identities`. I put a breakpoint on this line and found out that at that point it will have 2 identities. The `PolicyRequirement.Pass` method is run twice and I can't figure out why. How can I fix this and make sure that the `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity` has the correct identity that I set myself? Thanks in avance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Identity Web (MIW) will automatically handle adding the user to the identities variable. Therefore, if you want to take that authenticated context, with the identity pre-added by MIW, and replace it with your own, you would need to remove one of the identities.

By not removing the original user identity added by MIW you will, as you've pointed out, have two identities and the function will run for each identity.

The code you've supplied for `PolicyRequirement` doesn't seem to have an obvious need in my opinion. Maybe your intent is leading you own a rabbit hole when you already have a user identity to work with supplied by the MIW middleware.

I would also assume that every time you hit an endpoint with the `[Authorize("AzureAccount")]` attribute you will get an additional identity (2, then 3, then 4, etc...).